# Delete element from array based on condition and index

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have an array structure as below:

```js
[
  {key: 4, data: {…}, qText: {…}},
  {key: 4, data: {…}, qText: {…}, isVisible: false},
  {key: 5, data: {…}, qText: {…}, isVisible: false},
  {key: 4, data: {…}, qText: {…}, isVisible: false}
]
```

I wanted to remove  element from based on two conditions:

1. Suppose I get an key value input as 4 then all the keys with value 4 should be deleted.
2. The second scenario comes when the nested data with key:4 that is in the given example the second key:4 with index 1,suppose I get an index :1 and key 4 then only that specific key and index needs to be deleted

My approach included a lot of loops and was not effective. What would be the best approach performance wise to do it?
1)Tried to find the key as below

```js
const deleteKey = this.followUpQues.filter(quest =>
  quest.data.choice.some(y => y.id === item.id)
).map(quest =>
  quest.key
)
```

2)Tried to find the index as below

```js
this.followUpQues.forEach(function(val, index) {
  if (val.data.choice.filter(y => y.id === item.id).length >= 1) {
    keyNumber = val.key;
    valueIndex = index;
  }
})

this.followUpQues.splice(valueIndex + 1, this.followUpQues.length - (valueIndex + 1))
```

Comment: please add your approach and the wanted result.

Comment: "My approach included a lot of loops and was not effective" please include this approach in the question.

Comment: @NinaScholz  if you read the question have mentioned the wanted result

Comment: _"My approach included a lot of loops..."_ - Why plural? You only need one loop o.O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a working example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAbgQwDYFcCmEYF4YG0BQMMA3gNZoCeAXDACwA0MAJglAjcQL6MCOAKmgAeUDp26ES5anUYs2o3gOEKYASwgA1daoBGSNDQBmyCGnFEylGgFZZrdiW4x+QkY8bqtEXfqMmz9BKW0gzM9iouyu5qmtp6BjDGSKac+AC6+PiGKGDAUKrgMABOaAC2IHBoANKUABQIRUUI0ghgFLhpjFI0YCilOmhFHmBMQj19A0XYMAAMAJQkEkT6sMAojWhgUACSI0LTMwDcEoYgU7WgkLCIqGgwIIbwyOgQC8RLRGqPtTfoAHRSbBYHBSN4fT5fGAXdYlLa7UaCGAAHjUe0EYIhmJgaw2cLRAGp8ccsZwYGhknd3liiKMVncGk12jjYTs0WliZjUkRUql8CVypUahQfs8MIxQvNjvhLhAQPo-kgQABzEW3V6HIA):

```js
const values = [
  {key: 4, data: {}, qText: {}},
  {key: 4, data: {}, qText: {}, isVisible: false},
  {key: 5, data: {}, qText: {}, isVisible: false},
  {key: 4, data: {}, qText: {}, isVisible: false}
]

function removeKey(array: any[], key: number, index: number = 0) {
  let currentIndex = 0;
  for (const currentKey in Object.keys(array)) {
    if (values[currentKey].key === key) {
      if (currentIndex < index) {
        currentIndex++;
      } else {
        delete array[currentKey];
      }
    }
  }
}

removeKey(values, 4, 2);

console.log(values);
```

Do note that this mutates the original array. If you want to return a new array, you will also have to apply a deep-clone method.

Comment: Be careful with `delete array[currentIndex]`. This does work, but leaves the array with empty elements. For example take the array `[1,2,3,4]` using `delete array[2]` will **not** result in `[1,2,4]` but will result in `[1,2,<empty>,4]` instead.

Comment: I also just realized that the whole for-block logic is weird. You delete an element when `value.key` does not match the provided `key`. You only increment `currentIndex` if the `value.key` does match the provided `key` and `currentIndex` is smaller than the provided `index`. I suggest double checking your logic, something is not going right here.

Comment: You are indeed very right, I must have messed up somewhere. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to create a new array without the elements matching the criteria.

```js
const array = [
  {key: 4, data: {}, qText: {}},
  {key: 4, data: {}, qText: {}, isVisible: false},
  {key: 5, data: {}, qText: {}, isVisible: false},
  {key: 4, data: {}, qText: {}, isVisible: false}
];

const result = array.filter((obj, index) => !(obj.key == 4 && index > 2));
console.log(result);
```

If you don't want to create a new array, but instead want to modify the existing array I suggest using a reverse for loop. Using [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove elements. It's important that the loop is reversed because elements will shift when you remove them. Reversing the loop will still shift the elements, but the shifting elements are already handled/iterated.

```js
const array = [
  {key: 4, data: {}, qText: {}},
  {key: 4, data: {}, qText: {}, isVisible: false},
  {key: 5, data: {}, qText: {}, isVisible: false},
  {key: 4, data: {}, qText: {}, isVisible: false}
];

for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 2; --i) {
  if (array[i].key == 4) array.splice(i, 1);
}

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `slice` the list after a desired index and then `find` the item using a predicate (lambda) function. After you have found the item, locate the `index` of the item. If the `index` is greater than `-1`, let's remove it.

```js
const data = [
  { key: 4, data: '', qText: '' },
  { key: 4, data: '', qText: '', isVisible: false },
  { key: 5, data: '', qText: '', isVisible: false },
  { key: 4, data: 'Delete me!', qText: '', isVisible: false }
];

const remove = (list, predicate, fromIndex = 0) => {
  const found = list.slice(fromIndex).find(item => predicate(item));
  const index = list.indexOf(found);
  if (index > -1) list.splice(index, 1); // Remove
  return list;
}

console.log(remove(data, item => item.key === 4, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

---

**Caveat:** Since we are slicing the list after a particular index, we cannot use `findIndex`, because that would return the index in our sliced array. This could be modified to take into account the offset.

```js
const remove = (list, predicate, fromIndex = 0) => {
  const foundIndex = list.slice(fromIndex).findIndex(item => predicate(item));
  if (foundIndex > -1) list.splice(foundIndex + fromIndex, 1); // Remove
  return list;
}
```